# Get all composite foreign keys

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

**I'd like to know how to get all composite foreign keys, using Information Schema Views.**
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2

Here is my code to get all composite primary keys

```
select distinct tc.TABLE_NAME, key_col_us.COLUMN_NAME
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as tc inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE key_col_us on tc.TABLE_NAME = key_col_us.TABLE_NAME
 group by tc.table_name, key_col_us.COLUMN_NAME
having count(key_col_us.ORDINAL_POSITION) > 1
 order by tc.TABLE_NAME;
go
```

Thanks

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2